Possible sci-fi movie: people living underground, girl throws someone in a river, love triangle
I know in this film there is a group of people living underground. They do jobs like trim wheat in a meadow based there and there is also a cave with a fast flowing river. There is a main character girl and a main character boy. At some point the girl goes to the fast flowing river as she is escaping the leaders, I think, (she has upset them for some reason) and one of them finds her and tries to throw her in the river. Somehow she turns it around and throws him in instead and has murder on her hands. I know also that at the end she has an operation in the infirmary which they are unsure she will wake up from. Also I remember in the infirmary earlier someone (a boy who she is involved with romantically?) attacks her? She also has two love interests which she struggles picking between. There is a scene where she is in her room (it's like a clay structure because everything is underground) and she is talking to one of the love interest boys, then the other walks in and you instantly feel the tension. Also, the main boy character finds something (I think it's something inside the wall somewhere, I can't recall) and shows the main character girl. Anyone know anything?

It seems like the second half of the host 2013 
Image from the river scene
Image of the leads underground
Trailer but it don't shows any of the underground scenes



